# Is "IMPORT ADDRESS TABLE" of PE per dll or per exe?

Tags: windows, dll, exe, portable-executable

Does anyone know whether the 'import address table' in the PE executable format on Windows is 'per dll' or 'per exe'?

Answer (score 2):

Any PE can have an import address table, so both DLLs and EXEs can have them.  This makes sense since both can have dependencies (imports) on other binaries.  Unless you're doing dynamic loading (`LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`), you'll have an import address table when calling into another module.

You can use the `dumpbin` utility with Visual Studio to see the imports of a PE:

An example on user32.dll:

> **C:\Windows\System32> dumpbin /imports
>   user32.dll**
>
> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE
>   Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file user32.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> Section contains the following
>   imports:
>
> ```
> ntdll.dll
>           7DC60000 Import Address Table
>           7DCCACEC Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>               15A NtOpenKey
>               7A9 wcscat_s
>               7AD wcscpy_s
>                   ...
> ```

...and for notepad.exe...

> C:\Windows\System32> **dumpbin /imports
>   notepad.exe**
>
> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE
>   Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file notepad.exe
>
> File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
>
> Section contains the following
>   imports:
>
> ```
> ADVAPI32.dll
>            1001000 Import Address Table
>            100A234 Import Name Table
>           FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>           FFFFFFFF Index of first forwarder reference
>
>   77C71C82    27E RegSetValueExW
>   77C7BCD5    26E RegQueryValueExW
>   77C7BED4    230 RegCloseKey
>                   ...
> ```

Comment: If A.dll depends on B.dll and C.dll, then A.dll will have an IAT (if B.dll and C.dll have imports, then they, too, will have an IAT).  In the IAT for A.dll, there will be two `IMAGE_IMPORT_DIRECTORY` entries: one for B.dll and one for C.dll.  The structure is explained well here: http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html

Comment: So I was wrong,there will be only 1 IAT at the top level,right?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the top level"?  For *every* PE (DLL or EXE in your process), you can have the following: the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` which points to a `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` which can have a `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` containing many `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY` structures, one of which points to the set of `IMAGE_IMPORT_DIRECTORY` structures (one for each dependency the PE has).  This group of `IMAGE_IMPORT_DIRECTORY` structures can be considered to be the IAT for the PE.

Comment: I just read the article you cited,it says **This is a table of function pointers filled in by the windows loader as the dlls are loaded. ** , so the contents of IAT is not visible in a hex viewer,but only when it's loaded,right?

Comment: Yes, the actual addresses themselves are filled in at runtime by the loader.  The point of the IAT is to be able to dynamically resolve where a function is located.  This allows DLLs on Windows to change independently of one another (patches, updates) without breaking automatically.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

IAT(Import Address Table) is per PE file(dll and exe).

### Long answer:

When the loader load exe file its copy each section of the PE to the process memory, unless IMAGE_SCN_MEM_DISCARDABLE is set for this sections. The IAT is in the .idata section ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)):

> The PE file's .idata section contains the information necessary for the loader to determine the addresses of the target functions and patch them into the executable image. The .idata section (or import table, as I prefer to call it) ...

IMAGE_SCN_MEM_DISCARDABLE is not set for idata section. Therefore- idata section copied to memory, and both exe and dll have this section- meaning IAT is per PE.

I wrote a simple dll loader [here](https://github.com/lidorco/Loader), if it help you understand.